# Wordpress metadata for an image attachment

Tags: wordpress

I need a bit of help to display all the metadata for an image attachment.
Right now I'm struggling with displaying the *mime_type (file type)* and *filesize*.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
    $metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata();
    printf( __( 'Uploaded on: <time class="entry-date" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time></span><br />
    File URL: %3$s<br />
    Dimensions: <a href="%3$s" title="Link to full-size image">%4$s &times; %5$s</a><br />
    Post: <a href="%6$s" title="Return to %7$s" rel="gallery">%8$s</a><br />
    ', 'mytheme' ),
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date() ),
        esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url() ),
        $metadata['width'],
        $metadata['height'],
        esc_url( get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) ),
        esc_attr( strip_tags( get_the_title( $post->post_parent ) ) ),
        get_the_title( $post->post_parent )
    );
?>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood, maybe once you have the uri, you can use native php's [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) and [finfo_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

Now I see you've also got the wp native [wp_check_filetype](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_filetype)

And as an alternative (remember that in wp everything is a post, even images), you've got this that allows you to pass the post ID instead of the filename/uri: [get_post_mime_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_mime_type)

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, images will normally have multiple sizes. The metadata array gives information for each, e.g.

```
$metadata = Array
 (
   [width] => 2400
   [height] => 1559
   [file] => 2011/12/image.jpg
   [sizes] => Array
       (
           [thumbnail] => Array
               (
                   [file] => image-150x150.jpg
                   [width] => 150
                   [height] => 150
                   [mime-type] => image/jpeg
               )
           {medium] => Array
           ...
```

If all of your image sizes have the same mime-type, you can look in the array and get mime-type from the 'thumbnail' entry.

As for filesize, I don't think that WordPress has anything builtin, but you can use:

```
filesize( get_attached_file( the_ID() ) );
```